# NodeJS - Read Buffer line by line synchronously => toString() failed

Tags: node.js, stream

I have been struggeling, and searching for a long time. I know there are answers about that, but none works.

I used fs.createReadStream and readLine for this. But It's using fs.close() to close FILE READING. so it doesnt work at all when used on a buffer. The reading on all files goes on without possiblity to interrupt it...

Then I used this :

```
const stream = require('stream');

let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(hexaviaFile.buffer);

bufferStream
    .pipe(require('split')())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){

        // pause the readstream
        bufferStream.pause();

        // DO WHATEVER WITH YOUR LINE
        console.log('line content = ' + line);

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        bufferStream.resume();

    }).on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.' + err);
    }).on('end', function(){
        console.log('end event !');

    }).on('close', function(){
        console.log('close event !');

    })
);

// toString() Failed
```

I get the [toString() Failed] error and searched about it, apparently it appears when the buffer is large than node buffer max size.

So I checked :

```
var buffer = require('buffer');
console.log('buffer.kMaxLength = ',  buffer.kMaxLength); // 2147483647
console.log('hexaviaFile.buffer.byteLength = ',  hexaviaFile.buffer.byteLength); // => 413567671
```

It's not the case as you can see numbers provided:
    * maxBuffer size = 2Go
    * my buffer = 0.4Go

I also tried some diffeent library to do so but:
1. I want to keep memory usage as low as possible
2. I need this reading to be perfectly SYNC. In other words, I have some   processings after the file reading and I need to complete all the reading before going to next steps.

I don't know what to do :) Any kind (of) help appreciated

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this post. I found a way to achieve this without errors.

It's given here : https://github.com/request/request/issues/2826

1st create a splitter to read string chunks

```
class Splitter extends Transform {
    constructor(options){
        super(options);
        this.splitSize = options.splitSize;
        this.buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
        this.continueThis = true;
    }
    stopIt() {
        this.continueThis = false;
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, cb){

        this.buffer = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, chunk]);

        while ((this.buffer.length > this.splitSize || this.buffer.length === 1) && this.continueThis){
            try {
                let chunk = this.buffer.slice(0, this.splitSize);

                this.push(chunk);
                this.buffer = this.buffer.slice(this.splitSize);
                if (this.buffer[0] === 26){
                    console.log('EOF : ' + this.buffer[0]);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('ERR OCCURED => ', err);
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log('WHILE FINISHED');
        cb();
    }
}
```

Then pipe it to your stream :

```
let bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(hugeBuffer);
let splitter = new Splitter({splitSize : 170}); // In my case I have 170 length lines, so I want to process them line by line
let lineNr = 0;
bufferStream
      .pipe(splitter)
      .on('data', async function(line){

          line = line.toString().trim();

          splitter.pause(); // pause stream so you can perform long time processing with await
          lineNr++;

         if (lineNr === 1){
              // DO stuff with 1st line

         } else {
              splitter.stopIt(); // Break the stream and stop reading so we just read 1st line
         }

         splitter.resume() // resumestream so you can process next chunk
    }).on('error', function(err){
            console.log('Error while reading file.' + err);
            // whatever
     }).on('end', async function(){
           console.log('end event');

           // Stream has ended, do whatever...

    });
```